# AutoMapper incorrectly maps property with name Type - how to handle for multiple classes

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, automapper-3

While maping objects with `AutoMapper`, we realized that if there is a property named `Type` in a class, and no explicit mapping has been defined, AutoMapper maps that property to the `Type name` of the source type!

To demonstrate, let's say I have following classes

```
public class SoldierDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }        
}

public class Officer
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string BaseGroup { get; set; }
    public DateTime ActiveFrom { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have defined the mapping (no mapping for `Type`)

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SoldierDTO, Officer>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.BaseGroup, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Category))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ActiveFrom, opt => opt.UseValue(DateTime.Now));
    //.ForMember(dest => dest.Type, opt => opt.Ignore()); //this works though
```

And let's map a simple soldier object with that

```
var soldier = new SoldierDTO { Id = 11, Name = "Rackham", Category = "Gunner" };
var officer = Mapper.Map<Officer>(soldier); //Type = "Entities.SoldierDTO"
```

Everything works fine, except, the `Type` property gets assigned a string value `"Entities.SoldierDTO"`, which is nothing but the full name of the source type! I can see there is a [known issue](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/413) on GitHub. And as they have suggested, if I use `Ignore()` on the property, it works fine.

But, I have many classes in one of my projects with a Type property. Is there any elegant way of handling this for all those classes without adding `Ignore` on all individual mappings?

---

**Edit**

I'm currently using `AutoMapper 3.3.1.0`. As stated in Yacoub's answer, this issue seems to have been fixed in version 4. I'll need some time to update the package, meanwhile some workaround would be helpful.

Comment: What is the version of AutoMapper that you are using?

Answer (score 2):

As you noted in your question this is a known issue, and it seems to have been solved in a later version. I tested your code in the latest version (4.0.4) and the issue is already solved.

So you might want to update your version of AutoMapper.

Comment: Thanks, that's great news! Unfortunately, it's a big shared project and I cannot upgrade the dll right away. I'll try to do that soon, meanwhile some workaround like some global config (I'm not sure if that exists) will be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Mapper.CreateMap is not thread safe. its is not a good way to use it in multiple places.

Create a static class file inside App_start and and register all the mappings there. So its initialized on application starts. Also you don't need to call Mapper.CreateMap in other places

```
public static class AutoMapperConfig
{

    public static void RegisterMappings()
    {
      Mapper.CreateMap<SoldierDTO, Officer>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.BaseGroup, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Category))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.ActiveFrom, opt => opt.UseValue(DateTime.Now));
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Type, opt => opt.Ignore());

    }
}
```

In global.asax.cs

```
 protected void Application_Start()
 {
   AutoMapperConfig.RegisterMappings();
 }
```

You can use Mapper.Map method in application places that is thread safe.

```
var soldier = new SoldierDTO { Id = 11, Name = "Rackham", Category = "Gunner" };
var officer = Mapper.Map<Officer>(soldier);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this problem has nothing to do with thread safety! All my mappings are in static class methods and they get called only once. That is not related to the problem.

Comment: "But, I have many classes in one of my projects with a Type property. Is there any elegant way of handling this for all those classes without adding Ignore on all individual mappings?"  this means for one mapping at least you have to create Mapper.CreateMap one time. so whats the problem now? can you explain your question more?

Comment: Please read the question again. Even just the subject line summarizes the problem.

Comment: If you don't want to use Ignore then add valueresolver to fix correct mapping of type property